# Change value of an input element in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, rhomobile

I need to change the text of an input element when a user clicks on it.

my js:

```
$('#list-add-contact').bind('click', function(){

    alert($('#list-add-contact').val())   //alerts "Add To Contacts"
    $("#list-add-contact").val("other val")
    alert($('#list-add-contact').val()) //alerts "other val"

});
```

However, the mobile browser displays "Add To Contacts".  It does not displays  "other val" 
Do I have to call some specific function? I know the value changes because I can see the new value in the alert, but it does not displays it in the UI

Thanks!

Comment: what type of element is `#list-add-contact`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed:

```
$('#list-add-contact').bind('click', function(){ /* some function */ })
```

to:

```
$('#list-add-contact').click( function(){ /* some function */ })
```

and it worked...

Answer (score 0):

try the focus event

```
$('#list-add-contact').bind('focus', function(){
```

look at the [api reference](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/textinputs/events.html)

Comment: This doesn't make a difference, he stated it is working, just not displaying.

Comment: sorry, i got you wrong. the placeholder solution ist the right way to do that!

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is delete the text after the input receives focus, the `placeholder` attribute (which does precisely this) is supported in most mobile browsers.

```
<input id="list-add-contact" placeholder="Add To Contacts">
```

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_placeholder.asp